# UNION ALL to add in missing dates to a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I currently use a UNION ALL to add in a row to my Big Query table based on the current_date - 1 to ensure that a row exists for 'yesterday':

```
SELECT
  RowDate,
  COUNT(*) AS Records
FROM
  table1
GROUP BY
  RowDate UNION ALL
SELECT
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(),
    INTERVAL 1 DAY) AS RowDate,
  0 AS Records
ORDER BY
  RowDate DESC
```

What I would like to do is add a row for every date within a range of dates. Is this possible within a view query, without setting up a separate table of dates?

Any help much appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use [GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#generate_date_array) function for this

For example:

```
GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31') AS RowDate
```

so, in your specific case it will be something like below

```
UNION ALL
SELECT RowDate, 0 AS Records
FROM UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2018-01-01', '2018-01-31')) AS RowDate
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you. I haven't ever used the GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY function.